# Is there any way we can check the provisioning details on the iPad and compare to the Xcode version

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am installing ipa file on the ipad but its not installing its giving error is there any way to check the provisioning details on the iPad and compare to the Xcode version .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plug your iPad in with the USB connection while Xcode is running.  In Xcode, select Organizer from the Window menu.  In the organizer, click on "Devices"  Each device, as well as your host mac, will show a list of the provisioning profiles it currently has.

Comment: but i am sending this to client don't have xcode how will he check

Comment: In System Preferences on his iPhone, go to General->Profiles.  That will list all the profiles on the phone.  Compare them to your Xcode listing.